# Simple portable HTTPS-only browser with one pinned CA

Tags: open-source, web-browser, networking, security, encryption

Is there somewhere a project for a simple browser, that:

1. Only allows HTTPS connections;
2. Trusts only one Certificate Authority (like a file `ca.pem` in browser's directory);
3. Can use client-side certificate (if there are files `client.pem` and `client.key` in browser's directory);
4. Does not store data to temporary files or persistent cache;
5. Secure (as least as secure as the framework it is based on, like with usual browsers)?

I think this can be done with QWebKit more or less easily.